# Google Drive does not work with the Files app on iOS 11

Tags: google-apps, ios

I can't use/see Google Drive files on the Files app on iOS 11. Instead it comes up with this error: [image: The error says "Content Unavailable"]

I have tried pressing Try Again several times but still will not work. It doesn't seem to be the Internet. Is there anything I can do to solve this issue or is it a fault that everyone is having?

Comment: are you able to see the files in the Drive app?

Comment: An updated Google Drive app was available in the App Store today (4/6/18).

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried making some files available offline on the google drive app but it didn't work. It is definitely not an internet connection issue since I have used different networks (including using my phone as a hotspot) and the problem persists. The files can be viewed on the google drive app with no problem

Comment: Do you have multiple Google accounts? I wonder if that may be a problem.